# mpandroid chart line data shows behind limit line

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am using mpandroid chart library.
The line line data set shows behind limit line.

Please provide any solution.

```
float increment = (rangeHigh - rangeLow) / 20;
float metricLine = rangeLow;

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    LimitLine llRange = new LimitLine(metricLine, "");
    llRange.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#b5eb45"));
    llRange.setLineWidth(10f);
    leftAxis.addLimitLine(llRange);
    metricLine = metricLine + increment;
}


LineDataSet lDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(entry1, "T3");
    //lDataSet1.setDrawFilled(true);
    lDataSet1.setColors(new int[]{getResources().getColor(R.color.purple)}); 
//resolved color
    lDataSet1.setCircleColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    lDataSet1.setCircleColorHole(Color.parseColor("#9c27b0"));
    lDataSet1.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(190, 190, 190));
    lDataSet1.setDrawCubic(true);

    //lDataSet1.setDrawFilled(true);
    lines.add(lDataSet1);
```